# How to initialize char array and empty it again and again in a loop before strcpy() in C?

Tags: c, loops, initialization, char

I want to reinitialize d everytime in a loop

```
     char d[90];   
     while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("Word: %s\n",ptr);
        //int k = 0;
        strcpy(d, ptr);
        d[sizeof(d)-1] = '\0';
        //something more
        ....
        ....
     }
```

Comment: then do it... what stops you?

Comment: is there any reason why d variable cannot be declared inside while loop?

Comment: @coelhudo yes "SCOPE". I suppose it will give a redeclaration error.

Comment: As stackoverflowers said to you in your other thread, you should use strncpy instead of strcpy to avoid copy a string ptr larger that d

Comment: Friends don't let friends use strncpy. If you want to check buffer lengths yourself, use strcpy. If you don't, use (or roll your own) strcpy_s so that you don't have to manually nul-terminate. stncpy's only virtue is that it's standard, all it does is replace buffer overruns on write with buffer overruns on read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to do anything "before" `strcpy()`. Calling `strcpy()` on the buffer `d` will overwrite whatever is in the buffer, and leave the buffer holding the string pointed at by `ptr` at the time of the call. There's no need for the assignment of the last character to '\0'.

Of course, if you're doing the explicit termination because you're not sure if the `strcpy()` will overwrite `d`, then you have a problem. You should use `strlen()` on `ptr` before the copy to make sure it fits, or use `snprintf()` if you have it.

Comment: @Alex: glad it helped ... And feel free to accept the answer, if you're satisfied.

Comment: strncpy is the safe version of strcpy rather than snprintf

Comment: @Pete: I disagree. The semantics of strncpy() are deeply strange, and I consider it best avoided. It has two major faults: it doesn't terminate the output string if the input is larger than the buffer, and it pads the output to its maximum size if the input is smaller. Very rarely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

memset(d, 0, 90)?

Answer (score 0):

unwind is exactly right. You don't need to do anything before strcpy(). However, if you find yourself later needing to initialize some memory to a particular pattern you can use this:

```
void* pointerToMemory;          // Initialize this appropriately
unsigned char initValue = 0;    // Or whatever 8-bit value you want
size_t numBytesToInitialize;    // Set this appropriately

memset(pointerToMemory, initValue, numBytesToInitialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `strcpy(d, ptr)`. `strcpy` will add the NULL terminator at the end for you, of course assuming `d` can hold at least as many characters as `ptr`.